# Rewriting code to remove loop-carried dependence

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, dependencies

I'm trying to rewrite this outer `for` loop to allow multiple threads to execute the iterations in parallel. Actually, for now I just want two threads to compute this although a more general solution would be ideal. The issue is that there's a loop carried dependence: `nval[j]` is added to the previous value of `nval[j]` along with this iteration's value of `avval`.

```
void loop_func(Arr* a, int blen, double* nval) {
    // an Arr is a struct of an array and len field
    assert(a->len < blen);
    long long int i = 0, j = 0, jlo = 0, jhi = 0;
    double        avval = 0.0;

    for (i      = 0; i < blen; i++)
        nval[i] = 0.0;
    const double quot = static_cast<double>(blen) / static_cast<double>(a->len);
    for (auto i = 1; i < a->len - 1; i++) {
        j_lower = (int)(0.5 * (2 * i - 1) * quot);
        j_upper = (int)(0.5 * (2 * i + 1) * quot);
        printf("a->val index: %lld\t\tnval index: %lld-%lld\n", i, j_lower, j_upper);
        avval = a->val[i] / (j_upper - j_lower + 1);

        for (j = j_lower; j <= j_upper; j++) {
            nval[j] += avval;
        }
    }
}
```

For convenience, I'm printing out some details that were printed via the `printf` above.

```
a->val index: 1     nval index: 1-3
a->val index: 2     nval index: 3-5
a->val index: 3     nval index: 5-7
a->val index: 4     nval index: 7-9
a->val index: 5     nval index: 9-11
a->val index: 6     nval index: 11-13
```

I'd ideally want to have thread 1 handle the a->val index 1-3 and thread 2 handle the a-val index 4-6.

**Question 1:** can anyone describe a code transformation that would remove this dependence?

**Question 2:** are there C/C++ tools that can do this? Maybe something built with LLVM? I will likely have a number of different situations like this where I need to do some parallel execution. Similarly, if there are general techniques that can be applied to remove such loop-carried dependencies, I'd like to learn about this more generally.

Comment: You can parameterize a thread function based on the start index of the for-loop and create a thread-safe job queue which keeps a record of which indexes have already been handed out.

Comment: Why are you doing `0.5 * x * 2`?  Is `nval` in-out, or does it always start as `0`?  `(j_upper - j_lower + 1);` that is a fancy way to say `1`.  Either this code is nonsense or not a [mcve].  Are those arrays **1 based?!**

Comment: `quot` in one case that I'm running is 2 so I put that here to make it concrete but it is actually different in the actual application. The arrays are zero-indexed (typical C arrays).

Comment: I updated the example to be more complete. `nval` is output only -- it's zeroed out before the computation

Comment: So the modified `nval`for `val = i` and `val = i+1` overlap. Then you would need someway to handle this overlap. maybe atomics. Or since you do not modify the input(`val`): you could decide to handle `nval` 1-7 by thread 1 and  `nval` 7-13 by thread 2, then you would not need any synchronisation.